# WebPack Only: Invariant Violation: Text components are not supported for now in ReactKonva. You text is: ""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

> Invariant Violation: Text components are not supported for now in ReactKonva. You text is: ""

This error only happens after being webpacked. (Running the code normally without webpack is fine). I'm seeing that the exact error usually means I accidentally typed some text somewhere in some tags in the jsx.[1](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/228)

But if my text is the empty string, "", then what does that even mean? There's NOTHING extra there? And why would web pack be inserting ANY extra characters in my code if normally its minimizing it down?

My react is 16.6, my react-konva is 16.6 and my konva is 2.6.0 .

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const {
  paths,
  outputFiles,
  rules,
  plugins,
  resolve,
  stats,
  IS_PRODUCTION,
  IS_DEVELOPMENT,
} = require('./webpack/config');

const devServer = require('./webpack/dev-server').devServer;
const { determineEntryPoint } = require('./webpack/utils')

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = env => {

  const { outputFilePath, outputFileName } = determineEntryPoint(env)

  const entry = [
    path.join(paths.javascript, outputFileName),
  ];

  plugins.push(
    // NOTE dont do this because we want one file
    // Creates vendor chunk from modules coming from node_modules folder
    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: 'vendor',
    //   filename: outputFiles.vendor,
    //   minChunks(module) {
    //     const context = module.context;
    //     return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
    //   },
    // }),
    // Builds index.html from template
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(paths.source, 'index.html'),
      path: paths.build,
      filename: 'index.html',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        removeComments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
      },
    })
  );


  if (IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
    // Development plugins
    plugins.push(
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: outputFiles.vendor,
        minChunks(module) {
          const context = module.context;
          return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
        },
      }),
      // Enables HMR
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Don't emmit build when there was an error while compiling
      // No assets are emitted that include errors
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    );

    // For IE babel-polyfill has to be loaded before react-hot-loader
    entry.unshift('babel-polyfill');
  }

  // Webpack config

  let webpackConfig = {
    devtool: IS_PRODUCTION ? false : 'eval-source-map',
    context: paths.javascript,
    watch: !IS_PRODUCTION,
    entry,
    output: {
      path: paths.build,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: outputFilePath,
    },
    module: {
      rules,
    },
    plugins,
    resolve,
    stats,
    devServer,
  }

  if (IS_PRODUCTION) {
    // build it into a lib if it's production, yo
    webpackConfig.output.library = 'seatingManager'
    webpackConfig.output.libraryTarget = 'window'
  }

  return webpackConfig
};
```